# Linear operator on an $n$ by $n$ matrix vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

What would be the matrix of a linear operator on the $n$ by $n$ matrix vector space. I am having difficulty in arranging the basis. A general example will do. The context is ex.12 of sec 5:4 of Hoffman and Kunze linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors constituting the basis of the set $\frak{M_{n,n}}$ of $n \times n$ matrices  are the $E_{i,j}$ (every entry = 0 but entry $ij$ equal to one). For example, for $n=2$, $M=aE_{11}+bE_{12}+cE_{21}+dE_{22}$ means that:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}=
a\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ c
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ d
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Why do we build operators in $M_{n,n}$? Often because it allows to express things in a simpler way (a classical feature in mathematics: climbing in abstraction = simplifying the issues). For example, being given a (fixed) matrix $A$, assume you are looking for all matrices $X$ that commute with $A$. Instead of expressing it as $AX=XA$, you build the operator $X \rightarrow AX-XA$ and consider that you look at the kernel of this matrix operator.

Comment: The exercise is,V the vectorspace of all n by n matrices over F and B is a fixed n by n matrix over F and L(B) and R(B) be the linear operators on V such  that L(B)(A)=BA and R(B)(A) =AB. Show that : det L(B) =det R(B) =(det B)^n